# Flex for mobile <s:list> messageFunction

Tags: apache-flex

Here is the code I am using in the label function.  Some of the values are numbers and some are strings.  It works:

```
private function getLabel (area:AreasVO):String
{
  return "Area Name: " + area.areaName + "  " + area.areaWidth + " X " + area.areaLength + " X " + area.areaHeight;
}
```

It produces: Living Room 14 x 12 x 9

In the message function, I want to mix some computations and strings...can't figure it out.  The AreasVO has all the measurements as Type:Number  So I can do something like this

```
private function getMessage (area:AreasVO):Number
{
return area.areaWidth x areaLength;
}
```

That will give me the area of the ceiling or floor...

What I want is to have this returned:

Totals for Living Room: Area of Ceiling = 144, LF of Walls = 64, SF of Walls = 642

When I try something like this:

```
private function getMessage (area:AreasVO):Number
{
return "Totals for Living Room: Area of Ceiling = " + area.areaWidth x areaLength;
}
```

I just get error upon error...Numbers as Strings or a bunch of others...How do I do this?

Comment: You can format code in your posts by highlighting it and using the curly bracket button. It'll make your posts much easier to read.  You are also more likely to get help if you explain what the "Error upon error" that you see are.  Try to relate those errors back to snippets of code.  Also tell us which component you're using a labelFunction / messagefunction on.  I assume--but am not sure--you are displaying data in a List.  If so, I suspect you need to perform your math calculations and then convert the results to a string when returning them.  I'm not completely sure if that is your issue

Comment: Thanks for editing...I actually was wondering how that happened.  First time on StackOverFlow and I didn't notice your post, I just kept seeing the "0" above.  Your assumptions are correct...using it in a spark list for mobile and need to do the computation outside the function?  But I can only have one function in the messageFunction.  I am guessing this must be a pretty common issue and therefore has a pretty simple answer, but i am a little green.  So, how would I "perform your math calculations and then convert the results to a string when returning them".  Thanks,

Comment: @Flextras...I just realized I have seen you speak before and I read your blog often...small world.

Comment: Thanks for watching me speak and reading the blog and all that. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose the bits of math you want to happen within parenthesis like this:

```
private function getMessage (area:AreasVO):String
{
    return "Totals for Living Room: Area of Ceiling = " + (area.areaWidth * area.areaLength);
}
```

Or
[In your AreasVO]

```
public function get computedArea():Number
{
    return length*width;
}
```

then in the original file

```
private function getMessage (area:AreasVO):String
{
    return "Totals for Living Room: Area of Ceiling = " + area.computedArea;
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried the above solution from shaunhusain and I get the following error:  1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type Number. JobAreas.mxml /SeamlessEstimates/src/views line 105 Flex Problem  I will try it as type string next.

Comment: oh yah the return type there has to be String

Comment: If you want it to remain a number make a getter function in your AreasVO that does the math and returns a number, will add an example up above.

Comment: this worked:  private function getMessage (area:AreasVO):String
{
    return "Totals for Living Room: Area of Ceiling = " + (area.areaWidth * area.areaLength);  BTW, guess I am missing something, but I tried to "highlight the text that is code and hitting the curly brace button (on my keyboard...must be somewhere else)  and it just deleted the code.  
}